# Used to or would?

Tags: word-choice, verb-agreement, expression-choice

Is it better to say "I would always lose when I played chess with my father" or "I used to always lose when I played chess with my father" ?
Please justify your choice!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Would" & " Used to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254185/would-used-to) (but see also jpyvr's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432325/would-vs-used-to)). I'll add that while jpyvr's teacher would only license "When I played chess with my father, I would always lose" and not the ordering here, they were being over-prescriptive: either way is acceptable. // 'Would' is more formal than 'used to'. ////  "I always used to lose ..." (informal) or "I used always to lose" is more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Neither of the cited references has a canonical (or "valid" on ELU) answer. The jury is therefore still out on that.

Comment: For one, "'Used to' can be used to talk about past states as well as past repeated actions and habits, but 'would' is only used to talk about past habits. 'Would' is not used to talk about past states." and more here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode69/languagepoint.shtml

Answer (score -1):

The former means that my father always beat me at chess, and now he may or may not beat me at chess. The latter means that my father always beat me at chess, but now I beat him  at chess.

Comment: Good comment. Not an answer. Please post it as a comment if you have the privilege.

Comment: -1 that's simply not true